# text-style authoryear-type citation call-outs with the "harvard" citation management package

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I am quite new in LaTeX. Recently I am preparing a manuscript for IOP journal publication. I am using a IOP template .tex file named `IOPLaTeXGuidelines.tex` which can be downloaded from IOP website. In conjunction with I also have to use `harvard.sty` and `dcu.bst` file for harvard-style (also known as authoryear-style) citation call-outs (with some modifications imposed by `dcu.bst`) as a requirement of the particular journal in which I will submit manuscript.

I have added a line `\usepackage{harvard}` in start of .tex file, and at the end before referencing I added `\bibliographystyle{dcu}`. And everything works fine. But now I need a referencing in main text without parentheses, like this -

```
       John et al. (2018) have shown that .........
```

But what I have is -

```
       (John et al. 2018) have shown that .........
```

I am using TexMaker. All the staffs like `\textcite{}`, `\citep{}`, `\citealt{}`, ... I have tried. But nothing seems to compile.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please add a minimal working example along with a link to the journals template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `harvard` citation management package, you need to use

```
\citeasnoun
```

to create citation call-outs of the form

```
John et al. (2018)
```

---

It's actually *not* an iron-clad requirement to load the `harvard` package in order to use the `dcu` bibliography style. You could load the `har2nat` package instead (I will let you guess what it does) and keep using `\citet`, `\citealt`, etc.

Comment: If you're in the habit of loading the `natbib` package with various options, you should load that package first (with those various options) and only then run `\usepackage{har2nat}`.